# Condition almost equivalent to a map factoring through another map

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I came up with the following statement + proof. Does it look good?

Let $S$ be a set and let $f, g: S \to S$ be functions. Consider the following statements:

1. There exists an injection $h$ such that $f = h \circ g$.
2. $f(x) \neq f(y)$ if and only if $g(x) \neq g(y)$.
3. There exists an $h$ such that $f = h ∘ g$.

Then it is true that $(1) \implies (2)$ and $(2) \implies (3)$.

Proof of the first implication: $f(x) \neq f(y)$ implies that $g(x) \neq g(y)$ or else $f(x) = f(y)$. Similarly if $g(x) \neq g(y)$ then $f(x) = h(g(x)) \neq h(g(y)) = f(y)$ by injectivity.

Proof of the second implication: For each $x$ in $\text{im}(g)$, observe that $f$ is constant on the set $g^{-1}(x)$ by the hypothesis. Thus we can define $h: \text{im}(g) \to S$ by sending $x$ to the the single element in the singleton $f(g^{-1}(x))$, and clearly $f = h \circ g$.

Also, I was wondering if there was a name given to the relation given by statement $(2)$, that is, functions that disagree in the same places... do they share any nice properties?